# Unity StateMachineBehaviour : Start function called once?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm making my first enemy AI in unity. I'm trying to make a finished state machine with the animator controller to do it.

I just discovered the StateMachineBehaviour script which is called when the AI is in a state. It has multiple methods, including the OnStateEnter. It is called everytime the AI enter the state.

My problem is only about optimization, my AI need to get the GameObject "Player" in order to attack it. So i'm getting it in my OnStateEnter method for the moment, which i feel is bad, because i'm getting it every time the animation is called, i would like to get it only once, at the start.

I basicly need a start function but it's not working, i have made research and found nothing. I tried to watch video about people making a finished state machine but they are just getting the same GameObject multiple time ( example here : https://youtu.be/dYi-i83sq5g?t=409 ).

So, is there a way to have a start function or to get an element only once ?
I could make a bool that is called only the first time and that get the GameObject, but again that would be an "useless" if running in my function.

Any suggestions ? Thanks

Comment: Well, if i create a Start function with a Debug, nothing appear, so i guess the start function isn't implemented in the StateMachineBehaviour ? Or maybe i'm missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unlike a `MonoBehaviour` a [`StateMachineBehaviour`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.html) has no `Start` message only `OnStateEnter`, `OnStateExit`, `OnStateIK`, `OnStateMove` and `OnStateUpdate`.

There are also `Awake` and `OnEnable` but I'm pretty sure they are not used in the StateMachine and might not behave as expected.

---

You can however either use
[`OnStateMachineEnter`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/StateMachineBehaviour.OnStateMachineEnter.html)

> Called on the first Update frame when making a transition to a StateMachine. This is not called when making a transition into a StateMachine sub-state.

Or use a simple bool flag like

```
bool alreadyExecuted = false;

OnStateEnter()
{
    if(alreadyExecuted) return;

    // Do your stuff

    alreadyExecuted = true;
}
```

---

*(Just a guess)*
In the Inspector you actually can enable and disable `StateMachineBehaviours` like components. So it might be able to do this also in script maybe the same way using

```
enabled = false;
```

but I didn't find anything about it in the API and since I'm currently on my Smartphone I can't test it.

Comment: I was talking about making a bool at the end of my question, i'm not really happy about it because it's a check every time, but maybe i'm being a bit too picky here. There is probably no other way to do it.

Comment: You might be able to disable the behaviour on runtime but I currently can only make speculations about this (see my update)

Comment: And one additional bool check is really no expense to worry about ;)